# UILabel Issue preventing it from updating text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

Why is it that if you initialise a UILabel in the ".m" file to to 0 (which I know doesn't make sense as to why you would do that) in the "viewDidLoad" method, does it results in the UILabel's text becoming un-editable.

Example:

```
// foo.h
int intVariable;

@interface Game : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UILabel *fooLabel;
}

// foo.m
@interface()
@end
@implementation FooGame

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    fooLabel = 0;
}

-(void)MethodFoo{
    fooLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", intVariable];//<-This does nothing no matter what the value of intVariable.
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand: `fooLabel`, `foo`? If you do `fooLabel =0` that's may be the big issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `fooLabel = 0;` is the same as `fooLabel = nil;`.

This sets your outlet to `nil`. Any further use of `fooLabel` will be a no-op.

Comment: Thanks, thought this would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Why should `foo.text` update the `fooLabel` ?

Is it a typo or did you try `fooLabel.text` in your `MethodFoo` ?

**Update:**

*Deleted argument.*

Comment: `fooLabel` is an outlet. Most likely the label was created and set through a storyboard or xib. No need to create the label in code.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it should have been fooLabel.text. It was a typo that has now been corrected.